# Unindent does not match any outer indentation error

Tags: indentation

```
def convert(snippet, phrase):
class_names = [w.captialize() for w in          
               random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))   - line 36
other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
results = []
param_names = []error
```

I've received the following error after inputting the code:

> Unindent does not match any indentation level, Line 36.

Comment: Do y'all have any idea what is wrong with that code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you include a screenshot of your code? I think the markdown is clobbering your original indentation, and that makes it very hard to know what the issue is

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting basically just means you don't have the right amount of whitespace on a certain line. For example, the following code might generate this error:

```
def foo():
    print "bar"
  print "baz"
```

Note that the third line is unindented from the second line, which tells the interpreter that it has reached the end of the function definition, and yet the third line does not line up with any previous indentation, and so the interpreter does not know what it is supposed to belong to.

You should know that tab characters `\t` are counted as 8 spaces, even if your text editor only displays them as 4, so if two lines switch between tabs and spaces, it will confuse the interpreter